# How can I cast NSDecimalNumber from Objective-C to Float in Swift without compiler warnings

Tags: objective-c, swift, option-type

I have this function in **Swift 3**:

```
if let rating = product.rating as? Float {
    itemRating.update(rating) //sets item rating. Number of stars
}
```

where `product.rating` is a `NSDecimalNumber` coming from an **Objective C** function.

*I am in the midst of converting everything to Swift*.

Every time I call `itemRating.update(rating)` it gives the notorious:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The only way I got it to work was by this ugly implementation:

```
if let rating = product.rating as Decimal?, let floatRating = rating as? Float {
    itemRating.update(floatRating) //sets item rating. Number of stars
}
```

which always gives a warning:

> Cast from 'Decimal' to unrelated type 'Float' always fails.

Every other way I tried fails with the above error.

---

Here is the definition for `update()`:

```
- (void)updateRating:(float)inRating;
```

What is going on with this?

Comment: how is itemRating declared ?

Comment: It is of custom type which inherits `UIImageView`

Comment: If it crashes in `itemRating.update(rating)` then the conversion to Float is not the problem! Perhaps `itemRating` is `nil` ?

Comment: I tried adding breakpoints inside the `update` function. Doesnt even get inside `update`.

Comment: Add a `print(rating)` *before* that method is called.

Comment: Prints `4.12244`

Comment: Which means that the conversion is not the problem. Have you triple-checked that `itemRating` is not `nil` ?

Comment: That was it, I checked earlier but not surrounding that.

Comment: ... which means that your title and description do not match the actual problem. I would suggest that you either update the question (perhaps something like "how can I cast NSDecimalNumber from Objective-C to Float in Swift without compiler warnings"), or delete it. At present the question is unclear (and therefore useless) to future readers of this thread.

Answer (score 3):

if `product.rating` is really a `NSDecimalNumber` (not `(NS)Decimal`) instance just use optional binding to unwrap the optional then get the `floatValue` since `NSDecimalNumber` inherits from `NSNumber`.

```
if let rating = product.rating {
    itemRating.update(rating.floatValue)
}
```